# How can I mark a `DependencyProperty` as `BindsTwoWayByDefault` in UWP?

Tags: c#, xaml, uwp, uwp-xaml

In WPF you could mark a `DependencyProperty` on a custom control as binding `Mode=TwoWay` by default using [`FrameworkPropertyMetadataOptions.BindsTwoWayByDefault`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.frameworkpropertymetadataoptions(v=vs.110).aspx), but `FrameworkPropertyMetadata` seems to be missing in UWP.  The [UWP documentation on the `{Binding}` markup extension](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/xaml-platform/binding-markup-extension) says that the default mode may change, but gives no indication on how to affect it.

> #### Mode
>
> Specifies the binding mode, as one of these values: "OneTime", "OneWay", or "TwoWay". These correspond to the constant names of the BindingMode enumeration. **The default depends on the binding target** but in most cases it is "OneWay". Note that this differs from the default for {x:Bind}, which is "OneTime".

How can you change the default binding mode for a UWP XAML Dependency Property on a custom control?

Comment: Related, but not duplicate: [How to change default mode of x:Bind?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41691478/how-to-change-default-mode-of-xbind) (refers to `{x:Bind}`, which is distinct from `{Binding}`)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The current UWP SDK doesn't have any support for affecting the default `BindingMode` for a `DependencyProperty`; that is only possible within WPF.

On UWP all `{Binding}` have `BindingMode.OneWay` as default, while `{x:Bind}` has `BindingMode.OneTime`

Comment: Do you have a source for this?  While it matches observed behavior, it does contradict the documentation.

Comment: What documentation are you referring to? I can dig the links on the documents confirming this behavior, but here's a post I wrote a while back on this matter https://www.pedrolamas.com/2015/10/19/compiled-bindings-considerations/

Comment: The blog article you refer to seems to describe the `{x:Bind` markup extension.  The [UWP documentation on the `{Binding}` markup extension](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/xaml-platform/binding-markup-extension) says that the default mode may change.

Comment: Fair point on that, but basically, the documentation is wrong!! I've contacted Microsoft and that will soon be corrected to match the information in my answer here.